# Create JSON based on Python 3 dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, qualtrics

I'm currently working on setting up an automation based on API calls for updating embedded data to survey responses in Qualtrics using Python3, and the input for these calls is the payload JSON, which consists of the `responseId` and the embedded data fields to update.

My question is the following. How can I create a JSON using that follows the below structure using a dataframe?

```
payload = {
    "updates": [
        {
            "responseId": "R_1111",
            "embeddedData": {
                "ED_FIELD_1": "new_value",
                "ED_FIELD_2": "new_value"
            }
        },
        {
            "responseId": "R_2222",
            "embeddedData": {
                "ED_FIELD_1": "new_value_2",
                "ED_FIELD_2": "new_value_2"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ignoreMissingResponses": False
}
```

I just need to update one embedded data field called `Division` and my source dataframe has the following structure, containing around 6k records:

| response_id | division |
| --- | --- |
| R_12345 | Div_1 |
| R_67890 | Div_2 |

I've tried using the 'json' library and dicts but this only works for one record since dicts cannot be used in loop operations (or at least I haven't found the way to do it).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to create dictionary from the dataframe in question:

```py
payload = {"updates": [], "ignoreMissingResponses": False}
for resp_id, div in zip(df["response_id"], df["division"]):
    payload["updates"].append(
        {"responseId": resp_id, "embeddedData": {"Division": div}}
    )

print(payload)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "updates": [
        {"responseId": "R_12345", "embeddedData": {"Division": "Div_1"}},
        {"responseId": "R_67890", "embeddedData": {"Division": "Div_2"}},
    ],
    "ignoreMissingResponses": False,
}
```